# Mars Pictures Taken By MOM

Tags: mars, imaging, mars-orbiter-mission

I was looking for pictures of Mars taken by spacecrafts and came across this [news article](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/After-scripting-space-history-Mangalyaan-starts-clicking-images-from-Mars/articleshow/43352300.cms) of MOM taking its first pictures, however there no images in the news article.

Can anybody please tell me where can I see the real picture of Mars either taken from MAVEN or from MOM?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the only image taken by MOM that has been publicly released so far (credit: ISRO):
[image: MOM first light]

MAVEN doesn't have any visible light cameras.

Many previous Mars flyby and orbiter missions have taken tens of thousands of pictures of Mars; [here are a few nice ones](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/index/Mars.html).

Answer (score 1):

For all MOM images as they become available, see

http://www.isro.org/pslv-c25/Imagegallery/mom-images.aspx

The most recently posted image is [image: An almost full image of Mars from MOM]
<sub>(source: [isro.org](http://www.isro.org/pslv-c25/Imagegallery/satellitesimages/img-4.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Beside the image posted by @pericynthion MOM had clicked 5 more images. They are going to be soon released by ISRO. Also they are preparing for investigation on Comet Siding Spring. You can have details in these articles:

timesofindia.com/home/science/After-Mars-MOM-looks-to-sniff-methane-on-Comet-Siding-Spring/articleshow/43449086.cms

phys.org/news/2014-09-india-spacecraft-mars-photos.html